# check hdmi port status

Tags: lubuntu, hdmi

I have a Asus UN42, the HDMI port seems is not working anymore, no signal is sent through this port, tried different cable. I now use the displayport.
Is there any command to see what the problem is? Something to know the status of the HDMI port.

UPDATE

xandr produces this output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 885mm x 498mm
  1920x1080      60.0 +   50.0     59.9     30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
  1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
  1680x1050      59.9  
  1600x900       60.0  
  1280x1024      75.0     60.0* 
  1440x900       59.9  
  1366x768       59.8  
  1280x800       59.9  
  1152x864       75.0  
  1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
  1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
  832x624        74.6  
  800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
  720x576        50.0  
  720x480        60.0     59.9  
  640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
  720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

lshw -C display produces:

```
  *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 0b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:61 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Now I'm using a displayport to HDMI cable plugged in my displayport. The HDMI has always worked fine, I was using a HDMI to DVI cable to connect my PC to the display, until suddenly stopped working without a reason apparently..

Comment: What's the output of `xrandr` ?

Comment: updated with output of xandr and lshw

Comment: Sounds like a hardware error based off the symptoms.

Comment: can you explain more in details please? I'd like to understand how things works.. :) What, in the output I provided, suggest you ? In other words, what are the symptoms are you talking about? thank you